# bitbake remove inherit in .bbappend

Tags: bitbake

I want to remove 'inherit' using .bbappend.

For example,

In component.bb :

```
inherit something
```

In component.bbappend:

```
"remove_inherit" something
```

How I can remove inherit configuration using bbappend?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, this is not possible. All you can do in `.bbappend` is to override variables, defined in the original `.bb` recipe. So graceful solution would be exactly this - look carefully through original `.bb` recipe, understand how it works and tinker it in your `.bbappend` by overriding variables and functions, that originally were defined in `.bb`-file and `.bbclass`-files it was inherited from.

Optionally there is a bruteforce solution - just copy-paste original `.bb`-recipe (*and all it's accompanying resources*) into your layer and do with this whatever you want))